# Why does my text shows cyan background despite having a transparent background?

Tags: linux, windows, google-chrome, firefox, genexus

I'm a tester of Genexus and I'm working on a Linux while my programmer is working on a Windows.

I'm having a problem with a text because on my computer (Linux using Firefox/Chrome) I see the text with a Cyan background-color while my programmer working on Windows and Chrome he sees the background color as transparent.

He showed me the properties of the text and the background color is set to transparent.

[image: rgb]

Comment: Tough to isolate without posting any html and css. Display quirks as described can  sometimes be caused by css errors. Try checking stylesheets with a [CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), maybe check markup as well: [HTML Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Are you using a *browser extension* that changes the colors of your pages? Those extensions interfere with the test suite.